# How To Write Your Own FTP Uploader with Automator

Tags: xcode, macos, file-upload, ftp, automation

Is it possible to write your own application/command that will allow you to automatically upload your files to your ftp server?

Basically the flow I want to achieve is this

My app/action/whatever is scheduled to upload at a certain time
When the certain time arrives, the files in my specified folder will be uploaded
Of course, to upload, some data must be set like the username, password, ftp server etc...
After my files have been uploaded, the local files will be wiped-out.

I don't exactly know where to start. Can someone help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://editkid.com/upload_to_ftp/. It comes with the source code so you can modify it to fit your needs. You can combine it with an Automator action to delete the files after upload.

To schedule it, http://smallbusiness.chron.com/schedule-automator-tasks-mac-os-x-39132.html.

Comment: hi there. i know about this but i've been told that i need a unix script so i could schedule it properly? i'm quite not sure about those things as i don't even know how to write a unix script. Do you know how? I hope you can enlighten me. Thanks.

Comment: You can use a Unix script if you really want to... or you can have an app do the work for you. Check out [Cronnix](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/7486/cronnix) -- it's free and open source and it can run an Automator workflow that you've saved as an application.